# Can we add two Java versions in one Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, version

Recently I have worked on integrating remote Websphere Application Server with Jenkins. The server was running on java 1.6 and Jenkins with java 1.7 in my machine. I have faced an exception called `ClassChangeErrorException`. I have resolved it by changing Jenkins java version to 1.6. My question is can I have two java versions in one Jenkins?

Comment: There are Jenkins plugins to select JDK versions. You can also try to specify Java version in POM file and perform mvn build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

1. Define two jdks in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> JDK installations:

[image]

2. Specify needed jdk in job configuration:

[image]

Comment: No such section in Jenkins 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Java Versions available Globally through <jenkins_url>/configureTools/ after version 2.0 or <jenkins_url>/configure before version 2.0.

Source: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204960114-How-to-set-the-available-JDK-versions-